# Swift 1.2 is broken when using constant value within nested blocks

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I made a bouncing animation (with some wisdom here to prevent flickering) with the following UIView animation block:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
       options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse | .CurveEaseInOut,
       animations: {
           UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(1.5)
           cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y -= 25.0
       }) { (finished) in
           UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
                  options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                  animations: {
                      cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y += 25.0
                  }, completion: nil)
}
```

This worked perfectly fine, but then when I abstracted out the constant '25.0' from the two blocks like so:

```
let yDisplacement = 25.0

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
       options: .Repeat | .Autoreverse | .CurveEaseInOut,
       animations: {
           UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(1.5)
           cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y -= yDisplacement
       }) { (finished) in
           UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
                  options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                  animations: {
                      cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y += yDisplacement
                  }, completion: nil)
}
```

... the Swift compiler started to complain:

`Could not find member 'Repeat'`.

I couldn't for the life of me figure out why this was happening, until I realised via binary chop that the problem was the constant.

Anybody know why this happens? Or whether this is fixed in Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When upgrading this code to Swift 2.0 the error also points to `.Repeat` but states:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

I managed to fix it by being explicit with the `yDisplacement` type:

```
let yDisplacement: CGFloat = 25.0
```

As you cannot use the `-=` or `+=` operators on `CGFloat` and `Double` operands.

This error seems terribly misleading as it is highlighting completely the wrong part of code.

Final code:

```
let yDisplacement: CGFloat = 25.0

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
       options: [.Repeat, .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], // Swift 2.0, use .Repeat | .Autoreverse | .CurveEaseInOut in Swift 1.2
       animations: {
           UIView.setAnimationRepeatCount(1.5)
           cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y -= yDisplacement
       }) { (finished) in
           UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0,
                  options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                  animations: {
                      cellToAnimate?.layer.position.y += yDisplacement
                  }, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Accepting this more complete answer!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that type of `yDisplacement` is defined as Double, but you cant mix types in arithmetic operations. In your case you want to subtract it from CGFloat `position.y`.

Just define type explicitly:

```
let yDisplacement: CGFloat = 25.0
```